# \ref before \label fails to evaluate running lualatex from Latex workshop

Tags: cross-referencing, luatex, latex-workshop

I am using Latex Workshop on visual studio code.

My lualatex tool is:

```
{
    "name": "lualatex",
    "command": "lualatex",
    "args": [
    "-synctex=1",
    "-interaction=nonstopmode",
    "-file-line-error",
    "%DOC%"
    ],
    "env": {}
}
```

My recipe is:

```
{
    "name": "lualatex x2",
    "tools": [
    "lualatex",
    "lualatex"
    ]
},
```

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Pictures
\usepackage{amsmath} % Maths formulas
\usepackage{amssymb} %Maths symbols like R and N
\usepackage{subcaption} %Subfigures
\usepackage{float} % Float placement
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Pretty graphs
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, positioning, quotes, decorations, decorations.pathmorphing, arrows, arrows.meta, shapes}
\usegdlibrary{trees, force, layered, circular}

\title{My title}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\maketitle
\section{}
\subsection*{a.}
Some text Here \ref{fig:first}.
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}                
                \begin{scope}[every node/.style = {draw, circle}, semithick]
                    \node (s) at (3,3) {s};
                    \node (x) at (3,0) {x};
                    \node (y) at (0,3) {y};
                    \node (t) at (0,0) {t};
                \end{scope}
                \begin{scope}[->, >={Stealth}, semithick, auto=right]
                    \draw (s) edge ["1", swap] (x);
                    \draw (s) edge ["3"] (y);
                    \draw (x) edge ["1"] (y);
                    \draw (x) edge ["4", swap] (t);
                    \draw (y) edge ["1"] (t);
                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption*{A caption}
            \label{fig:first}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{scope}[every node/.style = {draw, circle}, semithick]
                    \node (s) at (3,3) {s};
                    \node (x) at (3,0) {x};
                    \node (y) at (0,3) {y};
                    \node (t) at (0,0) {t};
                \end{scope}
                \begin{scope}[->, >={Stealth}, semithick, auto=right]
                    \draw (s) edge ["1", swap] (x);
                    \draw (s) edge ["3"] (y);
                    \draw (x) edge ["1"] (y);
                    \draw (x) edge ["4", swap] (t);
                    \draw (y) edge ["1"] (t);
                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption*{Another caption}
            \label{fig:second}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

I am getting the warning "Reference fig:first on p[age 1 undefined." and the reference appears as an unresolved reference "??". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: unrelated but don't put `figure` in a `flushleft` it will not do anything useful

Comment: you have used `\caption*` so there is no number to reference

Comment: Removing the asterisk from caption and compiling twice worked. How can I hide the "(a)" though? Thanks for the reply anyway, if you write an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: surely you need the a, how else will the reader know you are referencing just the left half of the figure???

Comment: I want to address it as what is written inside \caption{My Name for this} or at any rate customise the prefix of the caption with something that is not (a) and that I choose.

Comment: `\ref` only produces numbers (or at least counter values like a b c in this case)

Comment: I am used to \ref being perfectly able to resolve non counters with \tag inside equations. I guess it's different for figures. At any rate, I'll mark your answer as the solution if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `\caption*` so there is no number to reference.